# Use Python 3.6.4 to download image and create folder by book id

Tags: python, image, directory, jpeg

Url

- http://url.com/749/page-1.jpg
- http://url.com/749/page-2.jpg
- http://url.com/749/page-3.jpg
- http://url.com/749/page-4.jpg

There are 4 jpg files in one book id.

There are 749 - 826 book id

The last urls are

- http://url.com/826/page-1.jpg
- http://url.com/826/page-2.jpg
- http://url.com/826/page-3.jpg
- http://url.com/826/page-4.jpg

I try use two "for loops and while loops" to get all url , but always failure.

```
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-

base_url = "http://url.com/"

page = "/page-"

jpg = ".jpg"


for bookid in range(749,827):
    url = base_url + str(bookid) + page
    for n in range(1,5):
        u = url + str(n) + jpg
        print (u)
```

The logic is that I wanna get 1 book id and 1-4 jpg, then create a folder by book id. Move 1-4 pages to folder one by one.

Comment: Please share the code you wrote.

Comment: Unless it's needed in a bigger program, it would be easier to do it in bash with `curl`, something like `for id in $ID_LIST; do mkdir $id; for i in 1 2 3 4; do curl http://url.com/$id/page-$i.jpg $id/page-$i.jpg; done; done`

Comment: Please share your code and errors your are facing with

Comment: @Pawamoy Thanks so much for help. I'll try your code in bash. but first I'll download ubuntu and install to VMware.

Comment: @sam I fill the code. but it's wrong.

Comment: @py-D I fill the code. but it's wrong.

Comment: Why you edit my question ? @sascha

Comment: Because the status **solved** is explicitly given by *accepting the answer* (green check icon) and adding it to the title is just noise. I also removed some irrelevant text from the question (which is arguable) to focus on the problem itself.

Comment: @sascha I see. Thank you for tell me. Thank you for edit. I've convert his code with python 2.x to python 3.6.4 and it works great. Solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import urllib
import os 
book_ids = list(range(749 ,827))
page_ids = ["page-1.jpg","page-2.jpg","page-3.jpg","page-4.jpg"]
all_url = []
base_url ="http://url.com/"

for book_id in book_ids:
    books =[]
    for page_id in page_ids:
       books.append(base_url+str(book_id)+"/"+str(page_id))
    all_url.append({book_id:books})
for data in all_url:
   directory ="new/"+str(data.keys()[0])
   if not os.path.exists(directory):
     os.makedirs(directory)
   count = 0
   for urls in data.items()[0][1]:
      #print urls
      filename = page_ids[count]
      #print filename
      fullfilename = os.path.join(directory, filename)
      urllib.urlretrieve(urls, fullfilename)
      count= count+1
```

now you have all url with corresponding book id  now it will download if there is some content hope it helps

Comment: Thanks so much for help ! You've done the first . The 2nd is how to download image by all_url ?

Comment: check now i added second

Comment: I'm using Python 3.6.4 in Windows 10. Your code works for Python 2.x ?

Comment: I try to solve this error :  'dict_keys' object does not support indexing

Comment: I can't fix this error:     for urls in data.items()[0][1]:
TypeError: 'dict_items' object does not support indexing

Comment: I've add tag for pythonanywhere .@Pawanvir-singh

Answer (score 0):

after you have url with you, you can download and store image as follow:

```
import urllib
import os
for bookid in range(749,827):
    url = base_url + str(bookid) + page
    for n in range(1,5):
        u = url + str(n) + jpg
        if not os.path.exists(str(bookid)):
            os.makedirs(str(bookid))
        urllib.urlretrieve(u,str(bookid)+"/page"+str(n)+".jpg")
```

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "G:\url2.py", line 15, in <module>
    os.makedirs(bookid)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python\lib\os.py", line 205, in makedirs
    head, tail = path.split(name)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python\lib\ntpath.py", line 204, in split
    p = os.fspath(p)
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not int

Comment: @Kanglando check now

Comment: @Kanglando I am not getting any error on my machine. Have you used updated code? that error was due to i provided bookid which was int to create dictionary.

Comment: I use Python 3.6.4 on windows 10. What about you ?

Comment: Well ." import urllib.request " , " urllib.request.urlretrieve("http://...")"  works in Python 3.x . @py-D

Comment: @Kanglando python 2.7 on Ubuntu16.04

Comment: Well. I can convert Python 2.x to Python 3.x